# Access Select Values from another value based on the current table value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 Tables in Access and I am trying to build a LookUp Query.  (I am new to SQL)

`Dogs`

- `ID`
- `DogName`
- `Type`      (`int`)  Either 1,2,3,4

`ClassResults`

- `ID`
- `ClassEntered`    (`int`) 1-24
- `DogName`

So in my lookup I am trying to find all the dogs from the `DOGS` table that if the `ClassEntered` is less than 12 select all the dogs with a `TYPE` 1 or 2.

`Dogs` Data Sample:

```
ID   DogName   Type
0    AAA       1
1    BBB       3
2    CCC       1
3    DDD       2
4    EEE       4
```

`ClassResults` Data Sample:

```
ID   ClassEntered DogName
0    6            ?????
```

So, the Drop Downlist for the `DogName` should be Showing:

```
0, AAA, 1
2, CCC, 1
3, DDD, 2
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT Dogs.DogName FROM Dogs, ClassResults
WHERE (IIf([ClassResults].[ClassEntered] < 10,[Dogs.Type]<3,[Dogs.Type]>2)) ORDER BY Dogs.DogName;
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT Dogs.DogName FROM Dogs, ClassResults 
WHERE (IIf([ClassResults].[ClassEntered] < 10,[Dogs.Type]<3,[Dogs.Type]>2)) ORDER BY Dogs.DogName;
```

I hope that makes sense.
Stephan

Comment: It almost makes sense, but... 1) the formatting is not complete so the critical details are difficult to read; 2) The relationship between the two tables is not explicitly stated and the sample data for `[ClassResults]` as "??????" doesn't help.  The sample data looks incomplete; 3) It is not clear why the dropdown list should include the 3 rows you indicate; 4) Should the dropdown list show the 3 bullets literally as you show them?  Because the SQL query you have only return the DogName and not any other columns as shown in the example items.

Comment: *As for the query*:  I suppose `[Dogs.Type]` causes an error and should be `[Dogs].[Type]`.  The FROM clause does not include a join condition (i.e. `ON` clause), so the query will initially return the full Cartesian product which is all possible combinations of rows from both table.  I assume that you want something like `FROM Dogs INNER JOIN ClassResults ON ClassResults.DogName = Dogs.DogName`.

Comment: And if the class is greater than 12, what gets shown?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use joins:

```
select * from dogs d
left join ClassResults c on d.dogname=c.dogname
where c. ClassEntered<12 and d.type in (1,2)
```

If you want to pick data from two different tables, you have to utilize joins.